# Omniauth with Google Oauth2 gives a loading error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, google-oauth

just by including the gem in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
```

I get the following error:

```
21:20:05 web.1  | started with pid 20590
21:20:14 web.1  | /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `require': cannot load such file -- omniauth/google/oauth2 (LoadError)
21:20:14 web.1  |   from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `rescue in block in require'
21:20:14 web.1  |   from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `block in require'
21:20:14 web.1  |   from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
21:20:14 web.1  |   from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
21:20:14 web.1  |   from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
21:20:14 web.1  |   from /Users/user/Sites/WISDOM/code/git/wisdom/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
21:20:14 web.1  |   from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
21:20:14 web.1  |   from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
21:20:14 web.1  |   from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
21:20:14 web.1  |   from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
21:20:14 web.1  |   from script/rails:6:in `require'
21:20:14 web.1  |   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
21:20:14 web.1  | exited with code 1
21:20:14 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

I use the following gems:

```
oauth2 (0.9.2)
rails (3.2.11)
devise (3.0.0)
```

I have seen this issue
https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/pull/32
but upgrading devise didn't help in this case.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', :require => "omniauth-google-oauth2"

Comment: Thank you @Debadatt, I had tried to include it in this way since there is another stackoverflow question with that solution. But in my case this didn't work and I still get the same error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Oauth2 with Devise and include omniauth-google-oauth2 in the following way in my gemfile:

gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', git: 'https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2.git'